# How to add substitution variables in cloud build when creating the trigger?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-cloud-build

There is a divergence between Google Cloud Console and Gcloud when creating a Cloud Build Trigger. On the Google Cloud Console it is possible to add the substitution variables during the creation process without having to necessarily submit a build. But I couldn't find a way to do it with `gcloud beta builds triggers create`. I've found that you can add substitution variables with the command `gcloud builds submit`, which will do it during the build process. I would like to be able to use gcloud the same way I use the Console, which is, inform the substitutions during the creation process. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it's not on the official documentation, but just noticed that if you run:

```
gcloud beta builds triggers create cloud-source-repositories --help
```

there is a section that describes adding substitutions to the trigger:

```
         --substitutions=[KEY=VALUE,...]
            Parameters to be substituted in the build specification.

            For example (using some nonsensical substitution keys; all keys
            must begin with an underscore):

                $ gcloud builds triggers create ... --config config.yaml
                    --substitutions _FAVORITE_COLOR=blue,_NUM_CANDIES=10

            This will result in a build where every occurrence of
            ${_FAVORITE_COLOR} in certain fields is replaced by "blue", and
            similarly for ${_NUM_CANDIES} and "10".

            Only the following built-in variables can be specified with the
            --substitutions flag: REPO_NAME, BRANCH_NAME, TAG_NAME,
            REVISION_ID, COMMIT_SHA, SHORT_SHA.
```

So the below command should work:

```
gcloud beta builds triggers create ... --config config.yaml \
--substitutions _FAVORITE_COLOR=blue,_NUM_CANDIES=10
```